# Java Hashmap Iterator Issue on conditon

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I am trying to loop through a hashmap which contains Sessions and IDs. Multiple sessions may have the same ID. On each method call, I need to iterate through the hashmap and find which sessions are listed against a given ID.

class contains:

```
private static Map<Session, String> peers = new HashMap<Session, String>    ();
```

Method contains:

```
for (Map.Entry<Session, String> entry : peers.entrySet()) {
                if(entry.getValue() == clientId){
                    Session peer = entry.getKey();
                    peer.getBasicRemote().sendObject(figure);
                   }
            }
```

But the problem is it runs only one time. Even I tried to get the size of hashmap and it given the exactly amount what I have.

Comment: You should compare strings with equals `if(entry.getValue().equals(clientId)){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the value is a String, you should probably compare it via equals(), as == only checks if two objects are the same object, but not if they are the same String. But that's only guessing.